# Serve large dataset w/ Docker, nginx, & django

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, large-data

I am working on a research project that involves large video datasets (100s of GB, possibly multiple TB in the near future). I am fairly new to linux, sysadmin, and setting up servers, so please bear with me. I've provided quite a bit of info, and let me know if there is anything else that would be helpful.

I am using Ubuntu, Docker (w/ docker-compose), nginx, Python3.5 & django 1.10

Uploading a large-ish (60GB) dataset leads to the following error:

```
$ sudo docker-compose build
postgres uses an image, skipping
Building django
Step 1 : FROM python:3.5-onbuild
# Executing 3 build triggers...
Step 1 : COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
Step 1 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
Step 1 : COPY . /usr/src/app
ERROR: Service 'django' failed to build: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/src/app/media/packages/video_3/video/video_3.mkv: no space left on device
```

My files are on a drive with 500GB free, and the current dataset is only ~60GB.

I found [this discussion on container size](https://forums.docker.com/t/increase-container-volume-disk-size/1652/2). Perhaps I am misunderstanding Docker, but I believe I just want my volumes to be larger, not the containers themselves, so this doesn't seem appropriate. It also doesn't use docker-compose, so I'm unclear how to implement it in my current setup.

Just to be clear, with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271773/docker-nginx-django-and-how-to-serve-static-files) I am able to serve static files & media files with a small test set of data. (unclear to me if they're serving from the django container or the nginx container, as the data appears in both containers via ssh)

How can I get my setup to handle this large amount of data? I would like to be able to upload additional data later, so if a solution exists that can do this without having to rebuild volumes all the time, that'd be swell.

## My Setup

*Directory Structure*

```
film_web
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── film_grammar
│   ├── #django code lives here
├── gunicorn_conf.py
├── media
│   ├── #media files live here
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── nginx.conf
├── requirements.txt
└── static
    ├── #static files live here
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
nginx:
  build: ./nginx
  volumes:
    - ./media:/usr/src/app/film_grammar/media
    - ./static:/usr/src/app/film_grammar/static
  links:
    - django
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes_from:
    - django

django:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./film_grammar:/usr/src/app/film_grammar
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres

postgres:
  image: postgres:9.3
```

*film_web Dockerfile*

```
From python:3.5-onbuild
ENV DJANGO_CONFIGURATION Docker
CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "gunicorn_conf.py", "--chdir", "film_grammar", "fg.wsgi:application", "--reload"]

VOLUME /home/alexhall/www/film_web/static
VOLUME /home/alexhall/www/film_web/media
```

*nginx Dockerfile:*

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

*nginx.conf*

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections   1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name film_grammar_server;

        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stdout info;

        location /static {
            alias /usr/src/app/film_grammar/static/;
        }

        location /media {
            alias /usr/src/app/film_grammar/media/;
        }


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://django:8000;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'd suggest to leave the data out from container and use volume _bind mounting_ to get the data in (`docker run -v <video data folder on host>:<video data folder on container>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build` starts by creating a tarball from the context directory (in your case `.`) and sending that tarball to the server. The tarball is created in the tmp directory I believe, which is probably why you're running out of space when trying to build.

When you're working with large datasets the recommended approach is to use a volume. You can use a bind mount volume to mount the files from the host.

Since you're providing the data using a volume, you'll want to exclude it from the image context. To do this create a `.dockerignore` in the `.` directory. In that file add all the paths with large data (`.git`, `media`, `static`).

Once you've ignored the large directories the build should work.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that these lines in docker-compose.yml were using a volume as you suggested. Is this not the case? 


    `volumes:`
            `- ./media:/usr/src/app/film_grammar/media`
            `- ./static:/usr/src/app/film_grammar/static`

Comment: Yes, you are using a volume, but that doesn't get used until after build.

Comment: Thanks! 

Adding the big media and static folders to the ignore did the trick. And now I understand the system a little better.